# How to change change table rows/columns view/display based on screen size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap and I have a drinks menu as below (view in Firefox).

This works well for mobile view. However, I cannot seem to get it to work for desktop where the cols move up say in a row.

Mobile/current view:

[image: Current menu view]

Desired outcome (however last element i could not get to line up correctly but the idea is there);

[image: Drinks menu desired outcome]

Current code (for saving length, items assumed in tr/td tags);

```
<div class="row justify-content-center pt-5 mt-5 mb-5 pb-5">
 <div class="col-auto">
   <table class="table-responsive">

    <!-- Red -->
    <tbody>
    <!-- drinks items -->
    </tbody>

    <!-- White -->
    <tbody>
    <!-- drinks items -->
    </tbody>

   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't really a Bootstrap question as tables simply aren't responsive. See the linked duplicates for ideas, or use other structures and apply suitable [ARIA roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/table_role).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could relay on a grid layout and set each category into a single table so it can wrap without the need to  touch/destroy the table-layout. You can also avoid mediaquery setting a min-width to the cells

Possible example with grid & auto-fill (ressources below the snippet to dig into)

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: double;
  margin: 1em 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20em, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 20em;
  background: lightgray;
}

caption {
  text-align: start;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

td:last-of-type {
  width: 5em;
  background: #bee;
  /*demo purpose*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Carte des Drinks</h1>
<div>
  <table>
    <caption>Category</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Category</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Category</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Category</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <caption>Category</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drink item</td>
      <td>Price </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

ressources

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example37/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax

---

**Possible versie with your markup, bootstrap and custom classes** (that one relays on flex, not grid , so different behavior to be expected)

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: double;
  margin: 1em 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  gap: 2em;
}
.d-table {
  display: table;
}
tbody:before {
  caption-side: top;
  content: attr(data-caption);
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: start;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
td {
  width: 15em;
}
td:last-of-type {
  width: 5em;
  background: #bee; /*demo purpose*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row justify-content-center pt-5 mt-5 mb-5 pb-5">
  <div class="col-auto m-auto">
    
    <h1>Carte des Drinks</h1>
    <table class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <tbody data-caption="Category" class="d-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody data-caption="Category" class="d-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody data-caption="Category" class="d-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody data-caption="Category" class="d-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody data-caption="Category" class="d-table">
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Drink item</td>
          <td>Price </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks - although that works well , my requirement is to use bootstrap - however perhaps i could take your advice and just create a table for each type.

Comment: oki, i'll update the answer , with a single table too (saw your edit ) tbodys are coming in usefull

Comment: @vornies, almost no Bootstrap website is without at least some custom CSS. It's not reasonable to expect  that yours won't have some. Even the Bootstrap team don't.

Comment: @isherwood , yeah I know this is the case however im not a front-end person , i really dislike css etc. it was just a requirement placed on me to use bootstrap.

Comment: @vornies just added a snippet with bootstrap and custom class. grid seems more efficient/clean to my point of view , at least you have options and ideas

Answer (score -1):

Need to make it responsive,can use @media screen and (min-width: 800px) to adjust ur css. Try https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp if need extra info.

Comment: :· I used to solve the problem with that before.... I adjust the margin n make it float...